# How does one publish games on XBox One and PS4 if not in one of the allowed countries?

Tags: publishing, xbox, playstation4

We want to publish our game on XBox One & PS4. According to Sony & Microsoft they plan to allow indie developers to self-publish games. Unfortunately this is their requirement:

[Sony](http://us.playstation.com/develop/)

> Located in US, Mexico, Central America, South America or Canada

[Microsoft](http://www.xbox.com/en-GB/developers/id)

> Located in Canada, Deutschland, Spain, France, Italy, UK, US or Japan.

Do you advise me to create a company in the United States just to publish games in my home in UAE?

How does one publish games on XBox One and PS4 when not in one of the countries listed in the requirements?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about business legalese.

Answer (score 3):

Ask Microsoft/Sony. It's not about what the law considers an US company, it's about their interpretation of what an US company is. They make their own rules here.

Sony says that you must be **physically** located in the Americas, so a post-box is unlikely to statisfy their requirements. Maybe you could get away with a staffed American publishing office which "outsources" the development to your location, but only they can tell.